# Order the list by another variable in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a vector x, and over 200 tables saving a list, when I am working with tables, I save them in .Rdata, when I load them in a list, it doesn't go with order I want, so now I have to order them again.

```
x <- c("table5","table7","table9","table2","table1")
list <- list("table7","table9","table1","table2","table5")
```

I want a list order as x variable, the output will be

```
[[1]]
[1] "table5"

[[2]]
[1] "table7"

[[3]]
[1] "table9"

[[4]]
[1] "table2"

[[5]]
[1] "table1"
```

Comment: Perhaps this `list[match(x, unlist(list))]`? But i'm a bit unclear on exactly how you are are you using this outside your example. Do you have a named list? How do you know what's in each slot?

Comment: Fixed it, got it right this time